# Multi-Threading in Eigen (OpenMP is not used)

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, parallel-processing, eigen

I have a problem in using multi-threading in `Eigen` library.
This is my code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include "Eigen/Core"
#include <QDebug>

using namespace Eigen;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Eigen::setNbThreads(6);
    qDebug()  << Eigen::nbThreads( );

    int n = 1000;
    MatrixXd A = MatrixXd::Ones(n,n);
    MatrixXd B = MatrixXd::Ones(n,n);
    MatrixXd C = MatrixXd::Ones(n,n);
    C.noalias() += A*B;
    std::cout << C.sum() << "\n";


    return a.exec();
}
```

Whatever I did `Eigen::nbThreads( )` always returns 1 no matter what number I used in `Eigen::setNbThreads(6)`!

I read [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html) but it actually doesn't say clearly about how can we actually run `Eigen` in parallel mode when `OpenMP` is not present!

I also did a lot of searches but all of them are used with `OpenMP`!

What just happened? Is `Eigen` only supports `OpenMP` for multi-threading or it has a built-in multi-threading too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may have a look at armadillo library if your are converting from a MATLAB script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eigen's built-in multithreading only works with activated OpenMP. If you did not compile with OpenMP, then `Eigen::setNbThreads(6);` does essentially nothing, otherwise it is essentially equivalent to calling `omp_set_num_threads` (from Eigen's point of view).

You can use Eigen in an application which itself is multi-threaded (the main caveat to be careful with are calls to `setRandom()` and related, as described on the page you linked to).

Also, if your own multi-threading is based on OpenMP, but you don't want Eigen to exploit multithreading, you can disable it, at compile time by defining `EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE`, or locally by setting `Eigen::setNbThreads(1);`.

Comment: I think I have found a bug or so regarding Eigen and multithread applications. Could you check it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66303635/performance-drops-when-running-eigen-dense-matrix-multiplications-over-multiple